# golang global variable access is slow in benchmark test

Tags: go

Here is a simple golang benchmark test, it runs `x++` in three different ways:

1. in a simple for loop with x declared inside function
2. in a nested loop with x declared inside function
3. in a nested loop with x declared as **global variable**

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

var x = 0

func BenchmarkLoop(b *testing.B) {
    x := 0
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        x++
    }
}

func BenchmarkDoubleLoop(b *testing.B) {
    x := 0
    for n := 0; n < b.N/1000; n++ {
        for m := 0; m < 1000; m++ {
            x++
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkDoubleLoopGlobalVariable(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N/1000; n++ {
        for m := 0; m < 1000; m++ {
            x++
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is as following:

```
$ go test -bench=.

BenchmarkLoop-8                         2000000000               0.32 ns/op
BenchmarkDoubleLoop-8                   2000000000               0.34 ns/op
BenchmarkDoubleLoopGlobalVariable-8     2000000000               2.00 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/cizixs/playground/loop-perf  5.597s
```

Obviously, the first and second methods have similar performance, while the third function is much slower(about 6x times slow).

And I wonder why this is happening, is there a way to improve performance of global variable access?

Comment: This kind of microbenchmark tells you practically nothing of value.

Comment: If I interpret the output of `go tool objdump` correctly (on Go 1.12 on amd64), the functions with local variables simply repeatedly increment a CPU register while the last function (unsurprisingly) requires some kind of memory access (or perhaps its just some kind of dereferencing; anyway, nothing beats a CPU register). But as Adrian mentioned, this benchmark is pointless. Benchmark code that does something useful. Time spent accessing variables is almost certainly dwarfed by everything else that's going on.

Comment: Go doesn't have global variables.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder why this is happening.

The compiler optimizes away your whole code. 300ps per op means a only a noop was "executed".

Comment: That's not it in this case. I see about the same results with a `b.Log(x)` at the end of each benchmark.

Comment: @Peter to see what the compiler does: Inspect the generated assembly.

Comment: I did. It has looping structures in all of the functions. See my comment on the question.